# JPA Criteria add one day to the selected date

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, criteria

I have a JPA criteria that selects the max date from a table and I want to select the following day, e.g. if the query result is `1/20/17` I want the result to be `1/21/17`

Here is my code:

```
    CriteriaQuery<Date> maxDateCriteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Date.class);
    Root<DatesClass> datesClassRoot = maxDateCriteriaQuery.from(DatesClass.class);
    maxDateCriteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.greatest(datesClassRoot));
    TypedQuery<Date> maxDateTypedQuery =  entityManager.createQuery(amortizationsQuery);
    Date maxDate = maxDateTypedQuery.getSingleResult();
```

I want to change the criteria to return the max date + 1

In oracle I will do it:

```
SELECT MAX(MY_DATE) + 1 FROM DATES_TABLE;
```

I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to keep the original Date object in the database?

Than I would add 1 day to the day you retrieved from your DB:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(maxDate); 
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
Date newMaxDate = c.getTime();
```

Comment: Thanks @MathiasGhys but I rather do it as part of the JPA criteria because my original criteria will return a list of dates e.g. for each person his max date...